# Javascript get name from data by id function

Tags: javascript

I need to create a function the would return the name of the car when given the id.

I have this data:

```
{
    "cars": [
        {
            "id": "661",
            "name": "ford"  
        },  

        {
            "id": "657",
            "name": "fiat",
        },

        {
            "id": "654",
            "name": "volvo",
        },

        {
            "id": "653",
            "name": "porche",
        },

        {
            "id": "650",
            "name": "mazda",
        }

    ]
}
```

So I've done this:

```
function getCarNameFromId(id) {

    theData = {
        "cars": [
            {
                "id": "661",
                "name": "ford"  
            },  

            {
                "id": "657",
                "name": "fiat",
            },

            {
                "id": "654",
                "name": "volvo",
            },

            {
                "id": "653",
                "name": "porche",
            },

            {
                "id": "650",
                "name": "mazda",
            }

        ]
    };

    console.log(theData.name);

}
```

then call it:

```
function getCarNameFromId('650');
```

How do I finish this code so I can get the code to return me the name of the id specified?

Comment: iterate cars array and check if id matches on every iteration, break and return when found. use .each() to iterate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JS solution

```js
var findCar = function(id) {
    var theData = {
        "cars": [{
                "id": "661",
                "name": "ford"
            },

            {
                "id": "657",
                "name": "fiat",
            },

            {
                "id": "654",
                "name": "volvo",
            },

            {
                "id": "653",
                "name": "porche",
            },

            {
                "id": "650",
                "name": "mazda",
            }

        ]
    };

    for (var i = 0; i < theData.cars.length; i++) {
        var car = theData.cars[i];
        if (car.id === id)
            return car.name;
    }
}
console.log(findCar("654"));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using any mordenr browser you can use find method to find object from array

```
function getCarNameFromId(id) {
    ......
    ..........
    .....
    var obj =  theData.cars.find( function(el) {
       return  el.id == id
    })
    if(obj){
       return obj.name
    } else {
       return ''; // or just without any value. 
    }
}
```

if still want to support old browsers i would recommand to use lodash.js or underscore.js

Answer (score 0):

```
cars.find(car => car.id === id).name
```

Reference:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions